# BDD Testing framework for Express.js

Tags: rest, node.js, bdd, mocha.js, vows

Here is what i need:

1. Must be able to run test in Jenkins
2. I want to test API, so I don't really care about functions and objects, I just want to make sure that when I send POST to /api/users.json, I will see that user in json array from GET /api/users/.

Is there any way I can run app and test in same process?

**UPD.**

Problem is half-solved: I have use mocha + should + restler to test my app. It is working. But How to set up jenkins to run these tests?

Comment: Any testing framework can do this.

Comment: To name a few: [Mocha](https://github.com/visionmedia/mocha), [Vows](https://github.com/cloudhead/vows), [nodeunit](https://github.com/caolan/nodeunit).

Comment: I know. I'm looking for an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Freestyle Job -> execute shell script ->

```
npm install
node run.js &
node_pid=$!
sleep 15 // so tests won't fail because server not yet started
./node_modules/.bin/mocha --reporter tap > results/s-api.tap
result=$? 
kill $node_pid
sleep 1 // so jenkins won't "scream" about leaked process
return result // we need return code of tests
```